# How can I instantiate an ArrayBuffer from a hexadecimal representation of an octet stream?

Tags: javascript

I have binary information coming over a TCP connection (WebSocket). This is traced to the console in an encoded format like so:

```
53 54 41 52 54 45 44 3a 31 34 32 38 36 30 32 30 38 37
```

I presume this is hex encoding of each of the bytes.

The information is actually protocol buffer information. I would like to write a function to decode it using a library I have. The first step is for me to create a buffer object of some kind to encapsulate the binary information for supply to the library.

I do not yet know the precise type expectation of the library, but it expects a binary buffer of some sort.

The protocol buffer decoding library API looks like so:

```
library.byteBufferToResponse(buffer);
```

How can I instantiate a "binary buffer" of some kind from a hexadecimal representation of an octet stream?

```
var octetStream = '34 36 10 04 1a 05 0a 01 30';
var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(); // How can I initialize this with the binary data?
```

Comment: The "octet stream" in your question is just an ordinary array of JavaScript numbers. Is that the actual situation, or do you really have some sort of binary buffer (somehow)?

Comment: as followup to that, do you need an ArrayBuffer (which is mostly useless on its own) or a Typed Array? In which case: it'll be better to describe the actual problem you're trying to solve (e.g. "I have a file that I'm load via XHR and want access to its data as `uint8`s") to prevent having this turn into an [XY problem post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I have binary data coming over a WebSocket connection. As a first step I would like to be able to use the representation of the binary stream as displayed to the console using a trace function. The console representation is something like `body=53 54 41 52 54 45 44 3a 31 34 32 38 36 30 32 30 38 37 37 38 36` which I interpret as hex encoded bytes. This is in the browser.

Comment: If you're receiving data via a web socket, isn't it *already* an ArrayBuffer?

Comment: @Pointy that may be so, but on this occasion I would like to use the values printed to the console as a hex-encoded binary octet stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a [Typed Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) to access the buffer. You can directly put that array literal you have into its constructor, it will construct a buffer or the appropriate size.

> like `body=53 54 41 52 54 45 44 3a 31 34 32 38 36 30 32 30 38 37 37 38 36` which I interpret as hex encoded bytes.

For that, you can use [`TypedArray.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from) with a map function:

```
var msg = "body=53 54 41 52 54 45 44 3a 31 34 32 38 36 30 32 30 38 37 37 38 36";
var arr = Uint8Array.from(msg.slice(5).split(" "), function(byte) {
    return parseInt(byte, 16);
});
var buffer = arr.buffer; // not sure you actually need this
```

Comment: `Uint8Array.from` is undefined. Is that a browser thing?

Comment: I am on Chrome 41.0.2. I have also tried Firefox 27.

Comment: OK, so this method is only supported on Firefox 38+.

Comment: I am trying `buffer = new Uint8Array(msg.length);
  buffer.set(msg.split(' ').map(function(i) { return parseInt(i, 16); }))`

Comment: @BenAston: you'd need to do `new Uint8Array(msg.split(' ').length)`, but yes that should work

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayBuffer`s are backings for typed arrays, so:

```
var arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(octetStream).buffer;
```

Comment: What form should the `octetStream` be in? An array of Uint8s? Can you show me how to create this? `Uint8Array.from` is undefined for me.

Comment: @BenAston: I changed it to `new Uint8Array()` after about thirty seconds; not sure how you were still seeing it. Anyway, yes, an array of bytes.