# Convert string to Uint8Array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string "ab05d705" and I am trying to convert it to the following so I can add it to a Uint8Array. So how do I convert the string `"ab05d705"` to

```
0xab,0x05,0xd7,0x05
```

to put into the following

```
var data = new Uint8Array([0xab,0x05,0xd7,0x05]);
```

Any help would be so appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/57805/251311

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I instantiate an ArrayBuffer from a hexadecimal representation of an octet stream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545531/how-can-i-instantiate-an-arraybuffer-from-a-hexadecimal-representation-of-an-oct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
var s = "ab05d705";
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i+=2)
{
    result.push(parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
}
result = Uint8Array.from(result)
console.log(result);
```

`parseInt(value, base)` creates a JS number combining the input and  given base - we're using base `16` in this case.

Answer (score 8):

A Uint8Array is basically an array full of charcodes, so you could split all the characters and convert them to charcodes, and then using that array and calling `Uint8Array.from` on it. Something like this should work:

```js
var string = "Hello World!"
var uint8 = Uint8Array.from(string.split("").map(x => x.charCodeAt()))
```

Comment: Amazing! It works like a charm when I replace `TextEncoder` with this in an environment that doesn't have support for `TextEncoder`.

Comment: This will only work correctly for ASCII characters. Characters outside the ASCII range (eg emoji) need more than 1 byte to encode in UTF8. This will generate garbage strings.

Comment: This works way better than TextEncoder because this doesn't impose a BOM

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Web API [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) to get a Uint8Array of UTF-8 bytes from a string:

```js
const encoded = new TextEncoder().encode('€')
console.log(encoded) // Uint8Array(3) [226, 130, 172]
```

Comment: Since node 11 this doesn't need to be imported anymore and is available on the global object

Comment: @baywet thanks! I removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you are coming from the future [Buffer.from(string, encoding)](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromstring-encoding) is probably the best option.

```js
const uint: Uint8Array = Buffer.from('string here', 'base64')
```

Comment: That's assuming Node. On the web, there's [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder).